# Can I reference an existing row in base table from inherited one?(postgres)

Tags: postgresql, inheritance

I'm trying postgres, version 9.2
Can I reference an existing row in base table from inherited one?
Example:
i have a "person" table and a "student" table which inherits from person.
As i understand, if i insert new student, automatically new person is added.
But i need to insert first the  person data, and then insert a reference to it and  student related data.

Answer (score 2):

*As i understand, if i insert new student, automatically new person is added*

No. Although you can select students by querying the person table, only the student table will be populated after an insert to the student table.

The relationship you want is foreign key not inheritance. Create the person id column in the student table and make it dependent on the person id on the person table.

Comment: Thank you!In my mysql version of database schema i used foreign keys.
But this "inheritance" provided by postgres dbms is not that kind of  inheritance i expected...